# Денежное вознаграждение за найденную ошибку на SO

Tags: дефект, статус-отклонено

Если я нашел ошибку на ресурсе Stack Overflow, выдаёте ли вы премии за них? Если  да, то какие расценки?

На таких глобальных ресурсах  как Facebook, выдаются вознаграждения за нахождения ошибок.

Comment: Лично мне не кажется, что так будет. Ведь ресурс некоммерческий, емнип, и его финансовые обороты куда меньше, чем у фейсбука. Тут все пользователи стараются сделать сообщество лучше своими личными усилиями. :)

Comment: какого рода ошибка?

Comment: Расценки: +1 к вашей доброте душевной)

Comment: Награды типично выдаются не за любые ошибки, а за *добросовестное раскрытие проблем безопасности*. Это я сейчас в целом, не про SO/SE. И расценки, я полагаю, варьируются в зависимости от серьёзности ошибки.

Comment: @D-side  А что значит - `за добросовестное раскрытие проблем безопасности`. Это как?

Comment: @gilo1212 это при нахождении опасной уязвимости, не эксплуатируя её, непублично раскрыть её администрации ресурса. Есть ещё некоторые детали, но главное это.

Comment: А каков род ошибки? Уязвимость в безопасности / xss / shell ?

Comment: Ребят, прошу не задавать мне вопросы подобного рода `А каков род ошибки?`, на них вам отвечать я не буду.

Comment: @gilo1212 вы задали вопрос, какие плюшки вам за это будут. Чтоб узнать, какие плюшки будут надо знать род ошибки. Не так ли? :)

Comment: @gilo1212 ошибку или уязвимость? это немного разные вещи :) ошибок тут полно, и за них никто не платит. насчет уязвимостей - публичной программы оплаты нет. их стоит репортить админам (можно прямо тут попросить Николаса написать вам в личку), и с ними уже договариваться насчет поощерения.

Comment: @intro94 Верно, но вы пропустили одну деталь из моего комментария `на них вам `.  Все правильно?) Вот еще одна - `выдаёте ли вы премии за них?` . Вы же никакие премии не выдаёте, верное же?)  Тогда получается что я обращаюсь наверное не к Вам, любезный?)

Comment: @PashaPash Это тоже я не буду никому кроме адм рассказывать

Comment: @gilo1212 мы же не просим саму ошибку. Мне до самой ошибки нет дела, но в принципе, некоторую помощь и мы можем оказать (например, уточнить к кому обращаться). Учитывая, что все, кто с вами общался сейчас (кроме меня) очень старый пользователи ресурса, сделавшие немалый вклад в его развитие. Так что могли бы просто уточнить, что вам нужен ответ **только от модераторов или разработчиков**. :)

Comment: @gilo1212, в общем если вашей суперошибки в OWASP top 10 нет, то ваша ошибка премии скорее всего недостойна

Comment: @gilo1212 уязвимость является результатом ошибок программирования, с этим все согласны. Но *ошибка на сайте* зачастую подразумевает не уязвимость, а визуальные ошибки, либо проблемы с использованием ресурса. Но никак не уязвимость. Это два отличающиеся понятия, хоть и взаимосвязанные. :)

Comment: @gilo1212 Николас - это и есть адм

Comment: @gilo1212 кстати, обратные кавычки стоит использовать только для выделения кода

Comment: @PashaPash Николас, насколько я знаю, просто модератор. :)

Comment: @intro94 нет, он сотрудник Stack Overflow. а остальные с ромбами - просто модераторы.

Comment: @PashaPash вот это новость. Спасибо, буду знать. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Этот вопрос был задан недавно на английском сайте Stack Overflow: [Does SO have a bug bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322634) и получил ответ от сотрудника компании ([в виде комментария](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322634/does-so-have-a-bug-bounty/322639#comment341980_322639)). Прилагаю свободный перевод:

1. Чтобы выдавать денежные награды, нужно заполнять налоговые документы и т.п., что под силу только крупным компаниям.
2. Пользователи сайтов рады сообщать о дефектах бесплатно [на сайте Meta Stack Exchange больше 15 тысяч сообщений о дефектах].
3. За раскрытие **серьёзной** уязвимости, имя пользователя помещается на [доску почёта](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) и они могут получить приз от компании, примерно такого же содержания как для модераторов (например, кепка, футболка, блокнот с логотипом компании). Но о деньгах речи нет и в этом случае.