# Почему в конкурсных вопросах нет опции назначить денежное вознаграждение?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, конкурс

Мне очень нравится стэковерфлоу, и лично мне не хватает сервисов платных вопросов.
Поясню: трудоемкость ответа на вопрос младшего разработчика (студента) с кодом в 20 строк - одна. Трудоемкость ответа на вопрос сеньора (с кодом в 200 строчек) - совершенно другая. Из-за этого падает вероятность получить компетентный ответ с ростом сложности вопроса. У нас есть "[конкурсные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)" где мы платим репутацией, но задавать их может быть неинтересно по следующим причинам:

**1.** Может прийти на стэк профессионал, с нулевой репутацией и очень сложным вопросом. Где ему взять репутацию?

**2.** Репа это как признание в деловом сообществе, отдавать её жалкааа.

**3.** Для некоторых крутых профи, +500 очков репутации (если у него  более 10 000) может вообще ничего не значить. А заработать даже тысячу рублей при ответе на вопрос - очень приятно.

По сути получается, что ты теряешь `50 - 500` очков репутации и можно сказать: организовать конкурс ≃ наказание, за плохие действия. По крайней мере последствия аналогичны.

Я считаю, что среди посетителей стэка есть платежеспособный спрос на консультации и code-review, и профессиональные ответчики, которые не прочь разжиться двадцатью баксами. В этом контексте, особенно обидно за русский стэк, что он [бесприбыльный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4146/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-stack-overflow-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-2016-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83).

**Вопрос-предложение:**  Давайте допилим сервис к стэкуоверфлоу, с возможностью назначать вознаграждение на вопрос деньгами. Если предложение противоречит базовым ценностям стэка, напишите, каким?

Comment: Есть конкретные примеры вопросов, где это было бы полезно?

Comment: @andreymal Да запросто. Я пощу стену кода - братья, запустите код, найдите ошибку, а то меня начальник завтра с утра естествовать будет)).

Comment: Николас постоянно рекомендует этот сервис: http://experts-exchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewKachalin подобные вопросы неформат и должны закрываться

Comment: @andreymal неформат вопросы как раз и должны компенсироваться денежными выплатами со стороны автора, в пользу комментатора.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin неформат вопросы должны в принципе отсутствовать на сайте. У нас здесь не форум для произвольной болтовни, у нас здесь база знаний, которая должна быть чётко оформлена и полезна не только автору вопроса, но и всем другим посетителям. В вопросах вида «Разберитесь с этим куском кода плз» мало полезного для базы знаний. Хороший вопрос должен содержать минимальный воспроизводимый пример, желаемый результат, текст ошибки и, в случае наличия дубликатов на сайте, объяснения, почему существующие варианты решения проблемы не помогли

Comment: @andreymal не серьёзно. Можно расширять стэк с приватными вопросами - после ответа на такой вопрос, его, к примеру закрывать для поисковых ботов, но оставлять доступными для человека с $регистрацией.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Денежное вознаграждение за найденную ошибку на SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3096/208074).

Comment: "трудоемкость ответа на вопрос младшего разработчика (студента) с кодом в 20 строк - одна. Трудоемкость ответа на вопрос сеньора (с кодом в 200 строчек) - совершенно другая." - на самом деле ни опыт спрашивающего ни объем вопроса никак не коррелируется с трудоемкостью ответа. Она напрямую зависит от умения задать вопрос. На иной вопрос новичка начинаешь ответ думать, и понимаешь - проще книгу посоветовать. А вот ответить на вопрос опытного человека, если вопрос из твоей области компетенции, как правило совершенно не сложно, и приятно.

Comment: А что если назначать вознаграждение в криптовалюте? Стильно, модно, итишненько и возможно решит часть юридических вопросов?

Comment: "запустите код, найдите ошибку, а то меня начальник завтра с утра естествовать будет" - фриланс. Решение + вознаграждение и люди там сидят именно за этим...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Если отвлечься от темы консультаций и рецензирования кода и попытаться ответить на вопрос *«почему на Stack Overflow (не только на русском) нет денежных отношений»*, то я вижу здесь по меньшей мере две причины:

1. Юридическая. Приём и отправка денег требует дополнительных усилий в каждой стране, где планируется работа подобной программы, — постановки на учёт, получения лицензий, уплаты процентов и открытия полноценных представительств, удовлетворяющих ряду жёстких условий. К тому же надо будет тут же начать соблюдать законы о персональных данных, банковской тайне, требования международных платёжных систем и т. д. и т. п. То есть удобство для части пользователей выльется для компании-владельца в дополнительные проблемы и убытки.
2. Психологическая. Сейчас люди просто помогают друг другу. Они отвечают в своё свободное время, в дружеской атмосфере, расслабленно и не сковывая себя никакими социальными обязательствами. В ответе допущена ошибка? Незначительную исправят другие, а значительную просто заминусуют (в чём, опять же, нет ничего страшного — достаточно удалить ответ, и репутация в ближайшую полночь по Гринвичу пересчитается так, будто ничего не было). То есть это чисто отдых и возможность порешать различные проблемы для дележа опытом и иногда разминки ума.

   Но как только отношения станут денежными, вся взаимопомощь попросту исчезнет. Это станет ещё одной работой (к тому же низкооплачиваемой), так как деньги требуют качественного и безошибочного ответа. К тому же что делать со всеми, кто вносит впоследствии правки в ответ? *Уточню: править может кто угодно и когда угодно, даже спустя многие годы после публикации ответа.* Забирать часть денег у отвечающего? Затребовать дополнительные деньги у спрашивающего, особенно если правка вносит значительное уточнение или исправление? Это ведь деньги, тут придётся всё фиксировать и кодифицировать до мелочей, выпуская толстые подшивки юридических документов. Ну а раз всё уходит в юридическую плоскость, то это точно очередная работа.

Comment: Мне почему-то ваш ответ понравился больше, чем предыдущего оратора.

Answer (score 7):

SO - это база знаний. Тут не фриланс биржа.

[Нужен ли нам «фриланс» на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7174/15479)

[А нужен ли [фриланс]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5798/15479)

Если человек готов заплатить, то ему проще пойти и заказать работу на бирже какой-нибудь. Когда я был в Эмиратах, то команда из Египта, участвующая вместе с нами в программе акселератора местного, делала [GitHelp](http://githelp.io/) - сервис для платной помощи экспертов. Тоже неплохая альтернатива.

Ну и, как мне кажется, для создателей SE - это очень много дополнительной головной боли. Слишком много юридической волокиты будет для компании такого масштаба.

Comment: А я не был в Эмиратах :(

Comment: @alexolut ну и хорошо. Делать там нечего. Песок и жара 40+

Comment: @Suvitruf, фриланс - это заказ работы, готового приложения. Мы здесь говорим об отладках определённого модуля, компетентной выписки из доков с разъяснениями, о случае когда человек задаёт очень серьёзный вопрос, а репа не позволяет его поставить на конкурс. Я говорю не о фрилансе, а о вознаграждениях 100-10000 рублей, сущих копейках для отвечальников.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin большая часть заказов на фриланс биржах - это мелкие скрипты за 20-100 долларов.

Comment: @Suvitruf то что русский стэк безприбыльный, может привести к деградации стэка. А так - оформить благотворительную организацию, 80% - автору ответа (субъекта благотворительности), 20%  - на ведение уставной деятельности организации.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, `то что русский стэк безприбыльный, может привести к деградации стэка` — то же можно сказать и о [любом другом сообществе в составе Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Ведь (практически) все они созданы и поддерживаются не компанией, а обычными людьми со стороны через [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, поясню: под покровительством компании (Stack Exchange Inc.) находится не два сайта, а гораздо больше. Причём почти все из них созданы, сформированы и управляются обывателями с разных уголков Земли, не находясь при этом на зарплате. То есть всё на чистом энтузиазме.

Comment: Исключение — языковые разделы StackOverflow (на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/), [русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [испанском](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [португальском](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) и [японском](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)). Это особые проекты компании ([всё остальное обязано быть на английском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5445/208074)), у которых есть специальные сотрудники-управляющие сообществами, работающие удалённо и получающие за это зарплату.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, `"то что русский стэк безприбыльный, может привести к деградации стэка"` - на чем основано это предположение?

Answer (score 7):

Вы покушаетесь на святое: зарабатывать деньги это прерогатива отцов основателей SO, а именно господ: Joel Spolsky, Jeff Atwood (он же @codinghorror) & Co.

А простые юзеры пусть даже и с виртуальными суперправами - обязаны генерить контент и тем самым зарабатывать реальные деньги для отцов-основателей и при этом некоторые из них еще и умудряются [оскорблять нас](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1024229860103749633)

Ответ, очевидно снесут - ну да ладно - мне не привыкать.

Comment: Нарушаете бинайс, уважаемый, пройдёмте в баню :)

Comment: @Other а зачем его в баню? Если бы я был бы создателем сайта, мне было бы глубоко пофигу, что юзеры про меня пишут. Ведь в терминологии скрам разработчики - это свиньи, а юзеры это куры, можно сказать петухи. Настоящую свинью не должно оскорблять мнение петухов.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, Это камерный юмор, не обращайте внимания.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю причем тут оскорбление, больше выглядит как нападки на Россию в смысле государства и власти, нежели на русских и тем более контент-мейкеров ruSO

Comment: @yolosora больше выглядит на хайпожорство. Все мы пониманием, что он эти слова никогда не произнесёт в реале, если он в здравом уме. Так что, просто балабол, не более.